# Why does the second body div not line up with the first body div?

Tags: html, css, css-float

[image]

Why is the **rowDiv** text not left aligned with the **ColumnDiv** text and how do I fix it?

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2" style="float: left;">
        <div id="d3" style="font-weight: bold; height: 20px; overflow: hidden;">
            ColumnDiv
        </div>
    </div>
    test text
</div>
<div id="d4" style="overflow: hidden;">rowDiv</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozxx9m5m/)

This is a simplified version of what I am working with, so I cannot remove/change any of the existing styles.  I can add classes/styles and HTML elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What *Will Reese* suggested will work but the right way to do it is to clear the floating children inside the parent.

There are a couple of ways to do this.

***First option*** (Add a clearing div inside the parent container. It should be the last element before the closing tag - see **DIV #D5**):

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2" style="float: left;">
        <div id="d3" style="font-weight: bold; height: 20px; overflow: hidden;">
        ColumnDiv
        </div>
    </div>
test text

<DIV ID="D5" STYLE="HEIGHT:1px; OVERFLOW: HIDDEN; CLEAR: BOTH;"></DIV>

</div>
<div id="d4" style="overflow: hidden;">rowDiv</div>
```

***Second option:*** Add clearing CSS properties to #d1

```
#d1 {
    *zoom: 1; /*IE7 < hack */
    clear: both; 
    /* Add your styling below. For example:*/       
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
    /*etc, etc...*/
}

#d1:before, 
#d1:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

#d1:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

***Third option - and imo the best because it's reusable :*** Create a .clear class and add that to the container that you want to "self clear".

```
<div id="d1" CLASS="clear">
    <div id="d2" style="float: left;">
        <div id="d3" style="font-weight: bold; height: 20px; overflow: hidden;">
        ColumnDiv
        </div>
    </div>
test text    
</div>
<div id="d4" style="overflow: hidden;">rowDiv</div>

.clear {
    *zoom: 1; /*IE7 < hack */
    clear: both; 
}

.clear:before, 
.clear:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Floating objects will stack left-to-right (or right-to-left) so long as there is room. Elements will just try to go around them. If you want to make sure your element is below any floating elements, you need to clear them with the `clear` property:

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2" style="float: left;">
        <div id="d3" style="font-weight: bold; height: 20px; overflow: hidden;">
            ColumnDiv
        </div>
    </div>
    test text
</div>
<div id="d4" style="overflow: hidden; clear: left;">rowDiv</div>
```